# Postgresql - Select if none satisfy the condition in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: postgresql

I have these tables. Each Item Group has many items through the 'item_ads' table (many-to-many).

**Item Groups** (Id)

**Items** (id | status )

**Item ads** (id | item_group_id | item_id)

I want to get all the Item Groups where none of the items has the status of 'success'. If there is only one I don't have to select it, nobody has to be "success".

I tried this but it's not working.

```
SELECT

    item_groups.id

FROM item_groups
INNER JOIN item_ads ON item_ads.item_group_id = item_groups.id
INNER JOIN items    ON items.id = item_ads.item_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM items WHERE items.crawling_status = 'success'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WHERE condition applies to all database. It means it will be true (will not exists) if only one successfull item exists in database. You must specify what sort of item you want to check in your condition. In this case you want item belonging to certain item_group. You can do it like that:

```
SELECT
    item_groups.id
FROM item_groups
INNER JOIN item_ads ON item_ads.item_group_id = item_groups.id
INNER JOIN items ON items.id = item_ads.item_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM items  WHERE item.status = 'success' 
    AND item_ads.item_id = items.id
)
```

You can also add `GROUP BY item_groups.id` if you want get each `item_groups.id` only once.

Also I can't understand what you mean by

> If there is only one I don't have to select it, nobody has to be "success".